# Best JSON parser for Android as or today?

Tags: java, android, json

I am currently creating an application and I now need to parse to JSON format etc. Which libraries as of today are the best recommended for Android device? I am handling from very small JSON feeds to large JSON so something that can handle both ok!

I'm looking at two libraries at the moment and can't decide which one would fit my needs.
1. Jackson
2. minimal-json

- Speed
- Resource use
- Ease of implementation(productivity)

Pros and cons on libraries would be appreciated!

Comment: Go for gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Have you tried [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: Any question that asks for "the best" something is is almost certainly asking for an opinion-based answer.  That makes it an inappropriate question to ask.

Comment: @StephenC I disagree. So you go through life never debating subjects? It is the best option to gain biased answers, as long as one can back up those biased thoughts, as I have asked. It is how one goes forward with knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

I am Genson author.

The classic Gson, Jackson or Genson should work for you.
I don't know about any real benchmark on Android.

- On a server Jackson in general is the fastest but also the biggest in size (could be a problem on android).
- Gson is the slowest of the three, but I know they have some specific code/optims for android, so maybe they perform better there. I like their design.
- Genson is in between (perfs and size). For some benchmarks Genson performs a bit better than Jackson. Overall it has good consistent performances independent from the data shape/size.

The ease of use is quite subjective. I would tend to think that Jackson is a bit more complex due to its larger API.

I don't know much about minimal-json, but it does not provide any databinding api...so you will use only its DOM structures and copy by hand the data to some POJOs. Not what I would call easy to use :) You would also have more object instances, so it is maybe a bit more memory consumptive...

If you want to use jackson, I would recommend you to have a look at jackson-jr, a version of jackson with less features but smaller in size.

But don't focus too much on performances, all have enough good performances for most use cases.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson/). It is really small and does a great job!
[image]

[More about the benchmark](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/Benchmarks%20&%20Metrics/).

You may also want to have a look to this [json4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wink/wink-json4j/1.4). Personnally I really like the OrderedJSONObject class, so I don't have to use some odd trick to sort my data.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will take a look at it, I have no idea why someone down voted you, how rude of them!

Comment: I found this benchmark which is interesting in performance matter. https://dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android